# Third timer's a charm

Tags: optimization, real, time, circuitry

[image: power outlet, 1-to-3 socket multiplier, 3 timers, 1-to-3 socket multiplier, light bulb]

Three motorized 24-hour
[light timers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_switch)
are arranged between a power outlet and a light bulb,
with timer A parallel to a [daisy
chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daisy_chain_%28electrical_engineering%29)
of timers B and  C.

For these timers, devise schedules
that produce the following repeated lighting pattern,
with the largest possible number D,
beginning when the outlet's power is switched on.

Light is on for D hours, off for N hours, 
                on for D hours, off for N hours, 
                on for D hours, off for N hours, 
                $~\,\vdots$

N may be any positive constant.
 
To reduce complications:

- When power is initially switched on, all dials point to midnight

  $\small\llap{\raise1mu\oslash\kern5mu}\raise8mu\strut$No two timers may ever
  simultaneously be at transitions in their schedules
  (from OFF to ON or from ON to OFF,
  whether the same or different between timers)
  even though the power switch may initially turn them on simultaneously

**If you are unfamiliar with these timers**

Each timer repeatedly cycles through
its schedule of 24 intervals that last an hour each.


•$~$ You preset each interval to ON or OFF


•$~$ A circular dial determines the current point in the schedule


•$~$ A motor rotates the dial to advance through its schedule
          whenever power is supplied to the timer


•$~$ When the dial is in an interval that was set to ON,
          the timer acts as a direct connection for power to flow
          between what is plugged into it and what it plugs into


•$~$ When the dial is in an interval that was set to OFF,
          the timer does not provide a power connection

Timers A, B and C combine to power each other and the bulb.


⇉$~$ Timers A and B run nonstop once the outlet is switched on


➘$\:\,$ Timer B supplies power— but only when
          its dial is in an ON interval — to timer C


↝$~$ Timer C runs whenever timer B is in an ON interval


 $~$ (That C can also be powered, through its outlet, by A
            <del>is</del> $ \kern-2mu
               \raise -8mu{\tiny\wedge}
                \raise16mu{\rlap{\kern-1em\sf\small might~be}} \kern-2mu$
           inconsequential in this configuration.)


↩$~$ Timer C also
          runs — powered from its *outlet*—whenever
          timer A and itself are both in ON intervals


⚠$~$ Timer C must, however, be powered by timer B, not just A,
          during each ON/OFF transition


💡$\,$ The light is on whenever timer A is in an ON interval
          *or* timers B and C are both in ON intervals

**Related puzzles**

[Odd hours with two timers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/25610/18129)

[Halve time with two timers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/25606/18129)

[Day and night of the two timers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/25812/18129)

<sup>(These puzzles are either directly from
 or related to actual botany experiments)</sup>

Comment: So settings for A, B, and C are each effectively a binary number between $1$ and $2^{24}-2$ (they cannot be only on or only off and may only switch at the stroke of an hour), and we must find the greatest $D$ such that $D,N\in \mathbb{N}$ (the light must change state, and they are limited to natural numbers from the operation of the timers)? Does that not make it impossible to have C never change state at the same time as A at some point after the power is switched on?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: the timer goes from OFF to ON after 1 hour (switched ON) and then goes from ON to OFF in another hour (switched OFF)

Comment: @jaydm26 The question states "Each timer repeatedly cycles through its schedule of $24$ intervals that last an hour each. You preset each interval to ON or OFF". So you can choose any of the $16,777,216$ schedules (perhaps except all OFF and all ON, as per my question) for each timer (and C only moves through it's schedule when B is ON). Although the vast majority of choices will not have a fixed period for both D and N.

Comment: Ah C runs when A and C are in ON intervals or when B is in an ON interval ...now we may be able to do it.

Comment: Latest pass, @JonathanAllan: It's true that the initial midnight is a *state* transition for both A and B, and possibly C, because they receive power for the first time. But this is not necessarily an OFF/ON transition in their *schedules* because it is caused by the main power switch. I think your reasoning proves that at most one timer may have a transition scheduled for midnight.

Comment: Human lives weigh little when real puzzles are in the balance, @Jasen, but
thank you for solving the mystery of why we couldn't buy a
[two-headed power cord](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=suicide%20cable)
and had to jerry-build one for a similar setup in a real experiment

Answer (score 4):

The answer is

> $D = 23, N = 1$

Because

> $B$ and $C$ can't switch!
>  Say $B$ and $C$ do switch, then they'll switch periodically with some period $T_{B, C}$ and $A$ switches periodically with a period of $T_{A} $.
>  Then they will both switch at time $gcm(T_{B, C}, T_{A} )$.
>  Where $ gcm$ is the greatest common multiple which is at most $T_{B, C}\cdot T_{A} $.
>  So $B$ and $C$ can never switch, so they're both OFF all the time.
>  So $A$ is ON for $23$ hours and OFF for one.

Comment: Exactly what I thought prior to the update

Comment: C can also be powered by A. Sorry about my claim that this is inconsequential, which was based on last-minute false reasoning when I was second-guessing my solution

Comment: Phew! Now that there's interdependency between $A$, $B$ and $C$ we have a much more interesting puzzle.  I'll leave my answer as it stands since it was correct at the time I posted. Was really getting into this puzzle before I saw this rather disappointing answer so can now get back to the ol' drawing board with added interest :)))

Comment: Ohhh, @PaulEvans, the claim may have been true after all and B and C might also be able to switch. Trying to wake up and convince all of us, myself included, at the same time.  In any case, the truly interesting version of this puzzle is the one least attended, [Day and night of the two timers](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/25812/18129).

Comment: Ah! I'm assuming no *offset* between the periods $T_{B,C}$ and $T_{A}$...

Comment: because time C can't sleep in the on-state the maximum time possible is 23 hours on.

Comment: Timer C will be at different points in its schedule at real hour 24 (real time 23:00-23:59) and real hour 48, so it can variably control the light bulb at those times if hour 24 of timer A is an OFF interval

Answer (score 1):

As an example of how this puzzle isn't necessarily
as convoluted as it might look,
this solution produces a 48 hour lighting cycle with
D = 41 hours *on* and N = 7 hours *off*.

> ```
>  Schedule A:  17 hours ON (abcdefghijklmnopq) + 7 hours OFF (rstuvwx)
>  Schedule B:   2 h ON (ab) + 12 h OFF (cdefghijklmn) + 10 h ON (opqrstuvwx)
>  Schedule C:   4 h OFF (abcd) + 9 h ON (efghijklm) + 11 h OFF (nopqrstuvwx)
>
>                      |<--------------- 48 hour cycle ----------------->|
>                      |<------ 24 hours ------>|<------ 24 hours ------>|
>  In short:
>
>  A     +17 -7  /24   |abcdefghijklmnopq.......|abcdefghijklmnopq.......|
>  B  +2 -12 +10 /24   |ab............opqrstuvwx|ab............opqrstuvwx|
>  C   -4 +9 -11 /24   |..            ..efghijkl:m.            ..........|
>  L     +41 -7  /48   |************************:*****************.......|
>
>  In long:
>
>      timer   ON >     abcdefghijklmnopq_______|abcdefghijklmnopq_______
>        A    OFF >                      rstuvwx|                 rstuvwx
>
>
>      timer   ON >     ab____________opqrstuvwx|ab____________opqrstuvwx
>        B    OFF >       cdefghijklmn          |  cdefghijklmn
>                         . . .  . . .             . . .  . . .
>                         .          .             .          .
>                         .(B,C OFF) .             . (B,C OFF).
>                         .          .             .          .
>      timer   ON >     __.          .__efghijkl:m_.          .__________
>        C    OFF >     ab.          .cd        : n.          .opqrstuvwx
>                         . . .  . . .             . . .  . . .
>
>                                                                 . . . .
>        light's  >     AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA       :AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA.     .
>         power   >                     BBBBBBBB:B                .(A,C .
>        sources  >                     CCCCCCCC:C                . OFF).
>                                                                 .     .
>                                                                 . . . .
>                      |<-------- light on for 41 hours -------->|off 7 h|
> ```

Another example produces a 48 hour lighting cycle with
D = 46 hours *on* and N = 2 hours *off*,
where **timer A actually powers timer C**, through C's outlet,
during an interval when timer B is OFF.

> ```
> Schedule A: 22 hours ON (abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv) + 2 hours OFF (wx)
> Schedule B: 3 ON (abc) + 4 OFF (defg) + 2 ON (hi) + 10 OFF (jklmnopqrs) + 5 ON (tuvwx)
> Schedule C: 2 OFF (ab) + 6 ON (cdefgh) + 2 OFF (ij) + 6 ON (klmnop) + 8 OFF (qrstuvwx)
>
>  (short format for A,B     |<--------------- 48 hour cycle ----------------->|
>   ON/OFF format for C)     |<------ 24 hours ------>|<------ 24 hours ------>|
>
>
> A           +22 -2 /24     |abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv..|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv..|
>                            |   :  :                                          |
> B  +3 -4 +2 -10 +5 /24     |abc....hi..........tuvwx|abc....hi..........tuvwx|
>                            |   :  :                                          |
> C   -2 +6 -2 +6 -8 /24  ON |__cdefgh_          _klmn:op_    __          _____|
>                        OFF |ab :  : i          j    :  q    rs          tuvwx|
>                            |   :  :                                          |
> Light     +46  -2  /48     |************************:**********************..|
>             light's  >     |AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA  :AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA  |
>              power   >     |  B:  :B            BBBB:BB                      |
>             sources  >     |  C:  :C            CCCC:CC                      |
>                            |   :  :                                          |
>                        00:00   defg                                          23:59
> ```

During hours 4 through 7 (03:00−06:59, interval `defg`),
timer C is powered by A while both are in ON intervals and B is OFF.


But during hours 2 and 3 (01:00−02:59, `bc`),
timer B is necessarily ON in order to
move timer C through an OFF/ON transition.


Also during hours 8 and 9 (07:00−08:59, `hi`),
timer B is necessarily ON in order to
move timer C through an ON/OFF transition.

Comment: Love your output. It looks so complicated that it could be puzzle in itself.